# Map 2 entities to third one gives hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping, join

I want to map Class A with collection of Class C.
And Class B with collection of Class C.

Here is my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
    Class A:
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "objectid" , nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Where(clause = "field= 'x'")
    private Set<C> cSet = new HashSet<>();

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
    Class B:
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "objectid" , nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Where(clause = "field= 'x'")
    private Set<C> cSet = new HashSet<>();

@Entity
@Table(name = "c")
    Class C:
    ...
    @Column(name = "objectid")
    private String objectid;
```

I got an exception:

```
hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: C column: objectid (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I tried using referencedColumnName  EX:

```
Class A:
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "objectidA" ,referencedColumnName="objectid", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Where(clause = "field= 'x'")
    private Set<C> cSet = new HashSet<>();
```

With no success.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How would that work? An item in table C with FK reference objectId 1 will be associated with an item A with ID 1 and an item B with ID 1. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `@JoinColumn` annotations then you will get `join tables`, one for A->C and one for B->C, which should be able to do what you want, though I didn't try it.